# Replacing old shower arm and head

Tags: bathroom, shower

I tried to replace my old non-standard Kohler shower head and arm. After I removed the arm, I realized that my shower hose is non-standard as well.   I have a male threaded fitting sticking out the bathroom wall Instead of the standard female threaded fitting inside.

I cannot find any shower arm on Amazon that fits it.

Mainly I want to install a handheld shower head.

Any advice on how I can install a new shower arm and head?

[image]

Comment: How do you know there's not a female fitting inside the wall?

Comment: Can you show us the original equipment that was removed? Can you explain how you "removed" the previous equipment (I ask because that pipe looks like it may have been cut off). These things will give us clues to try to help you.

Comment: It looks very much like that is a male threaded insert into a female threaded fitting in the wall. I also agree with @JimmyFix-it that it looks very much like it was cut off. Whether it was cut off by the OP or someone previous to him is unknown (though the rust on the cut end indicates it's been cut for a while. Additionally, the female fixture in the wall appears to be broken at the bottom.

Comment: I don't know. It took me a while to remove the Kohler shower head and arm. There might be a female fitting inside the wall but I can't tell for sure. I lack of tools to remove this part.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you will need a threaded coupler, female-female fitting.

You will thread it onto the male fitting and that will leave you a female fitting for a standard shower arm.

Take the old removed arm to the store so you can match the threads.