# Shower arm compatible with protruding water pipe

Tags: shower

My old shower arm started leaking so I needed to replace it, after getting it off I realized that the water pipe protrudes out, around 8cm. Here is an image:

[image: Protruding shower water pipe]

Are there any shower arms on the market that could still work with this? The house is very old and I see that all shower arms advertised assume to screw into the wall while this one needs to be screwed onto... I tried looking up terms like "screw on shower arm", "extruding shower arm" and the likes.

Edit: I also saw this post [Replacing old shower arm and head](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/218251/replacing-old-shower-arm-and-head) but the problem with mine is that the pipe is extruding quite a bit.

Answer (score 2):

You can cut that pipe 1" from the wall and add a compression to female thread fitting similar to the one shown below from Lowe's. Don't install the compression fitting inside the wall. Then get a bell escutcheon to cover the fitting similar to the one shown from Lowe's and screw your new standard shower arm into the fitting.

[image]

[image]